# Cannot create class file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

As you can see in the image below, when I try to create a class file this notification appear, I was looking for a solution here in SO and I checked other questions but none of them solved my problem, What do I need to do to solve this?

I hope you can help me, thank you.

[image]

Comment: What are the parameters that are hidden behind the error message?

Comment: @MingleLi the only thing selected is `visibility: public` and `modifiers: none` and the name of the class that you can see, the values that are selected by default

Comment: Is ASClass template is a custom template you create or a built-in template class?

Comment: @FadySaad built-in template because just right now i created the project and this class file is the first im trying to create

Comment: OK, can you tell me what is the directory you try to create the class on? I think you choose a wrong directory?

Comment: @FadySaad I try to create it in this path `src > main > java > com.mypackagename` inside is where is the mainActivity file

Comment: The last thing could be the name of the class, It could be already exists.

Comment: It looks like the template 'ASClass' does not have a valid structure, i.e. does not have the correct syntax for a Java class.  Locate the template using Preferences / Editor / File and Code Templates; if you created the template by mistake delete it; if you modified it by mistake correct its syntax.

Comment: @FadySaad it doesnt exist, I searched that file with the finder and no one result exist

Comment: @EdmundJohnson I didnt create any file and it doesnt exist in my project, this is weird

Comment: I am able to reproduce your error by doing Preferences / Editor / File and Code Templates / Files / Class, then in the template changing "File Header.java" to "File Header Hello.java".  Then saving preferences ("Apply") and back in the editor doing File / New / Java Class, name Goodbye, OK.  However the error message has "Class" rather than "ASClass", which implies a file type of "ASClass" in the templates. Try this out, and look at both Project and Default schema in the templates preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, and was able to resolve it by installing a fresh copy of Android Studio. 
(A bit) More detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46427285/3048930).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by deleting header generated automatically in a Java file. 
Go to : 
Preference ==> Search for header (in the top left input) ==>File header (make it empty) 
Hope I help you