# Android Studio won't create a class

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Why won't Android Studio create a class?

It doesn't even work for newly created projects

**Update**

OR why are all of these empty?

[image]

Comment: You cannot create a class with an empty package name. Though the error i get is not the same as yours if I try that

Comment: @Adam I have package `com.example.myapp` in this popup window, for this project everything was working ok before, I don't know why now it happens

Comment: @Adam it seems like I can't create classes for any other project, it just stopped working

Comment: There are others with your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497266/unable-to-parse-template-class, Also i  saw some comment which said that a restart of studio fixed it.

Comment: @Adam of course I tried restarting, `Go to File->setting->editor->file and code templates` I found out that everything is empty there (no just class)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you may have installed the 64 bit version on a 32 bit machine. I had the same problem. If you have 32-bit OS, try to uninstall 64-bit version of Android Studio and install 32-bit version from this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: it was working ok yesterday on the same machine (x64)

Comment: Go to:

Android Studio -> Preferences -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header

If you have defined some variables in the template, check how the variables are defined, should be (for instance):

#set( $USER = "Your Name")

instead of

#set( USER  "Your Name")

I hope it helps

Comment: everything is empty there

Comment: I think it just easier to reinstall studio

Comment: the best option would be reinstalling your studio with best configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same Issue. Go to your Android Studio -> Help -> Edit Custom VM options. Add the following line to the opened file.

> -Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false

Source : [Fix suggested by Wojciech Fred](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206922365-Unable-to-parse-template-Class-Error-message-This-template-did-not-produce-a-Java-class-or-an-interface-during-New-Java-Class)

Answer (score 0):

To me, the problem was due to incorrect upgrade to new version of Android Studio. Studio patching seemingly went ok, but at Event Log, I constantly got this error:

```
2:55 PM FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in /home/vlada/android-studio-145.3200535/lib/idea.jar
```

I also got similar message in 'IDE Fatal Errors' window.

Downloading and installing the latest version of Studio solved the problem for me.